# pass data-icon attributes in razor html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I want to following html code using asp.net mvc 3 razor html helper:

```
<input type="text" .... .   placeholder="Login" data-icon="user" />
```

I have try this one:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = "Login", data-icon = "user" })
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = "Login", @data-icon = "user" })
```

Displayed Error:

```
Invalid anonymous type members declaration.
```

This might due to dash in data-icon not taken as attributes. How could I add data-icon attributes in text box field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can't write like that but you can write your own Extension to solve this problem. Here is the sample code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyInput(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string value, string icon)
    {
        var attrs = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        attrs.Add("data-icon", icon);
        return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, name, value, attrs);
    }
```

Or you can also use in razor like this:

```
@{
    var attrs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    attrs.Add("placeholder","Login"); 
    attrs.Add("data-icon","user");
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, attrs)
```

Plz don't forget to mark it's right answer if it helps you :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot I was searching for long time in google could not found. Finally I got it. Thank you very much you are life saver

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = "Login", data_icon = "user" })
```

Comment: This.  It wasn't immediately apparent to me but after some testing the underscore gets turned into a dash.  In my case, data_placeholder is turned into data-placeholder.  Un(der)documented features FTW!

Comment: To me, this seems to be the intended and correct solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This is really the same as vNext's second alternative, but if you prefer to write it in-line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "placeholder", "Login" }, { "data-icon", "user" } })
```