# Using data- in custom helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 to write a web application. When I use `Html.ActionLink` to create a link I can pass data-anything attributes to action link in its `htmlAttributes` parameter. But I cant use `data-` and I should use `data_` instead. It seems that `ActionLink` changes `data_` to `data-`. How can I do this in a custom helper? In general how can I modify `htmlAttributes` passed to a helper?

```
public static MvcHtmlString AuthorizeModalLink(this HtmlHelper Helper, string Text, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var builder = new TagBuilder("a");
    builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag) + Text + builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11606534/729541) should help you out.

Comment: I modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes` parameter, you can just use `"data-foo"`.

You use `data_foo` when using an anonymous object. There's a function available to replace the underscore with a hyphen: `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)`

Example:

```
public static HtmlString CustomCheckboxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return CustomCheckboxFor(htmlHelper, expression, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}

public static HtmlString CustomCheckboxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string controlHtml = htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToString();

    return htmlHelper.FormItem(expression, controlHtml);
}
```